# Create auto dynamic URL for API call

Tags: php, api, url, dynamic-url

Is is possible to create dynamic API's url call?

For example, I have an API URL: `https://example.com/v2/user/signin`

I want to call this url every time with timestamp or some other noise like
URL : `https://example.com/v2/34348348349/user/signin`

Just want to secure my API call from any type of external attack. Although I am using user based APIKEY and also using Token, API LIMIT but still I am feeling insecure.

Your valuable suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add timestamp and parameters, AES encryption, encrypted strings as part of url, server access, decrypt the strings, determine whether the timestamp is within the error value, if the check is passed, continue business operations, if the error time exceeds, return error information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but please read my question again .